# Lightweight circular log (filesystem-like) algorithm for flash based storage

Tags: filesystems, arm

I am currently working on a project that involves rapid, continual logging of a rather application specific metric over a long lifetime.  To do this I ended up using an NXP M0 and a 32MiB SPI flash chip.  The logging is continual and needs to last many years in the field (10+), and is periodically checked by a human for trend spotting.  Eventually the buffer fills up and starts overwritting old data which is perfectly fine.  I came up with a simple algorithm to walk the whole flash device to find the current head after a power-up (the device is powered down rather frequently outside of my control) so logging can just continue where it left off.  I can just brute force through this walk and do it with ~4s as worst case scenario.

This got me thinking, are there any log structured filesystems that are catered to flash devices and microcontrollers?  JFFS and all the other well known [Log Structured FSs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_file_system) I imagine would be a little heavy for a simple microcontroller (depends on the application of course).  To be more specific, I would like to know of any algorithms that are designed to specifically be a circular log with fast head seek time and/or any that are designed for a "traditional" filesystem on a flash device that can be run on a microcontroller.  Traditional in this sense being on-par with something like JFFS where there is a data structure that represents a collection of mutable random-access files in a hierarchical name space.

Comment: I had a look recently and didn't find anything suitable (I'm in exactly the same situation as you). Started writing my own circular buffer. Got up to 600 lines of quite complex code before running out of time...